# Azure - Deploy Node app with worker, API and front end in a monorepo

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a monorepo which contains, an API, a React webapp and a worker.

I want to deploy this into Azure (first time doing so), however am unsure about the procedure I need to follow.

- I've created an App Service - however do I need to create multiple app services for each of the 3 pieces (api, worker and front end)? I've seen deployment slots - is it in here I specify how to run each of them e.g. `npm run api`, `npm run worker`, `cd front`->`npm run front`
- If I have to create 3 separate app services, as all my code is in a monorepo, when I update something will I have to deploy to each of the 3 app services?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes you can use multiple slots per same app plan, if you want to save costs and understands your apps computing needs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#should-i-put-an-app-in-a-new-plan-or-an-existing-plan)
- To control the CI/CD pipelines, use repo path filters (include/exclude) in each build pipeline to work only if specific app changed like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)

Comment: Can I not use deployment slots for each of the services? Additionally, as it is a monorepo, when I update the code, I need to redeploy to all 3 app services?

Comment: Thanks - getting clearer now. However where is it that I literally describe things like: Do `npm run build` then `npm run worker` for the worker. Do `npm run build` then `npm run api` for the API?

Comment: If it works for you later, mark the answer accepted ;)